# Ambiguity in an SQL query involving two joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables that are structured as follows:

```
results:
id | url_id

foo
id | url_id | url

bar
id | url_id | url
```

I want to be able to select the URL in a single query knowing that it could be in either table.

My plan was to do a `LEFT JOIN` on both of the tables and then return something like `IFNULL(foo.url, bar.url) as url`.

It is important that the result is called `url`.

However, I cannot use this same `url` column name in my `WHERE` clause because of the ambiguity. Here is my query and the error message I get:

```
SELECT r.id,
COALESCE(foo.url, bar.url) as url
FROM results r
LEFT JOIN foo USING (url_id)
LEFT JOIN bar USING (url_id)
WHERE url IS NOT NULL;
```

`Column 'url' in where clause is ambiguous`

It would be fairly trivial to select the column under a different name and rename it in my code, but it would be nicer to do it in SQL.

Here is an SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32abc6/4

Cheers

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You just need to provide the table name or alias in your clause - something like `WHERE table.url = x`

Comment: SQLFiddle is struggling at the moment, you should ***always*** include your code in the question.

Comment: Literally you want `WHERE COALESCE(foo.url, bar.url) IS NOT NULL`, or `SELECT * FROM (your base query) AS lookup WHERE url IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use an alias name declared in the `SELECT` clause in your `WHERE` clause, because `WHERE` happens before `SELECT`.

Hence:

```
SELECT r.id, COALESCE(foo.url, bar.url) as url
FROM results r
LEFT JOIN foo USING (url_id)
LEFT JOIN bar USING (url_id)
WHERE COALESCE(foo.url, bar.url) IS NOT NULL;
```

or

```
SELECT r.id, COALESCE(foo.url, bar.url) as url
FROM results r
LEFT JOIN foo USING (url_id)
LEFT JOIN bar USING (url_id)
WHERE foo.url IS NOT NULL OR bar.url IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

The direct answer to your question is to use table aliases when referring to columns.  I would write this as a series of left joins:

```
SELECT
    r.id,
    r.url_id,
    COALESCE(f.url, b.url) AS url
FROM results r
LEFT JOIN foo f
    ON r.url_id = f.url_id
LEFT JOIN bar b
    ON r.url_id = b.url_id;
```

This answer assumes that the actual `url` match could be in either table, or, if it matches to both, then you don't mind taking the version from the `foo` table.

Comment: This is what I was doing previously. I've linked an SQL Fiddle in the OP, hopefully that makes it clearer.

The error is specifically when I try and use the `url` column in the `WHERE` clause as it could be referring to either `foo` or `bar`, even though I aliased them in the join.

Answer (score 1):

Your error suggests to use table alias if same column name available with more than one table :

```
select f.id, ifnull(b.url, f.url) as url
from foo f left join
     bar b
     on b.id = f.id
where f.url_id = ?;
```

This answers your -> `Column 'url' in where clause is ambiguous` error, `JOIN`s  may not same as you want if so then adjust the `on` clause or provide one other conditions with `JOIN`. But the idea would be same to use alias to make it easier to understand the query or to compiler.

Answer (score 1):

if you want url on where you can use sub-query cause your both table has url column but you make one so either you have to use table.column name in where

```
select * from 
(
  SELECT r.id,
COALESCE(foo.url, bar.url) as url
FROM results r
LEFT JOIN foo USING (url_id)
LEFT JOIN bar USING (url_id)
)as t where t.url is NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have

```
SELECT ..., IFNULL(foo.url, bar.url) AS url
...
WHERE url LIKE ?      *** Error: "url" ambiguous
```

The sorry solution is to use:

```
SELECT ..., IFNULL(foo.url, bar.url) AS url
...
WHERE IFNULL(foo.url, bar.url) LIKE ?
```

It should not be less efficient. It is what one pays.
Maybe the following would work:

```
SELECT ..., z.url
FROM (SELECT IFNULL(foo.url, bar.url) AS url FROM DUAL AS z)
JOIN ...
WHERE z.url LIKE ?
```

Introducing a table alias for disambiguation.